# Why don't I have a local network URL?

Tags: create-react-app

After installing and running *create-react-app*

```shell
    npx create-react-app my-app
    cd my-app
    npm start
```

I see one URL:

```shell
    Compiled successfully!

    You can now view my-app in the browser.

      http://localhost:3000/
```

But I expected to see something like that:

```shell
    Local:            http://localhost:3000/
    On Your Network:  http://192.168.43.210:3000/
```

*System*: Linux Mint 19.1
*react-scripts*: "2.1.5"

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/6a5b3cdaaa7e9ee2cae358a50cf005af9d1408bd/packages/react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils.js#L79 and https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/6a5b3cdaaa7e9ee2cae358a50cf005af9d1408bd/packages/react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils.js#L59 indicate it's only set to show "on your network" in some situations (the presence of `urls.lanUrlForTerminal`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am under Wireguard VPN and I think my address is private now :(